# asp.net mvc3,c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want separate friends facebook and twitter.
Like this :

**Twitter**        **Facebook**

*EditorTemplates:* **FriendModel.cshtml**

```
@model App.Web.Models.FriendModel
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="saveInputs" value="@Model.FriendID"/>
<img alt="" src="@Model.ProfileImageUrl" />
<strong>@Model.Name</strong> Friends: <strong>@Model.FriendsCount</strong>
</div>
<br />
```

*Views:* **FriendTeam.cshtml**

```
@model App.Web.Models.FriendTeamModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "FriendTeam";
}
<h2>
  FriendTeam</h2>

 @using (@Html.BeginForm())
{          @Html.ValidationSummary(true)     
  <h3>Twitter</h3>
  <br />    
   @Html.EditorFor(model =>     model.Friends.Where(x=>x.SocialNetworkName=="Twitter"))                  

 <h3>Facebook</h3>
  <br />    
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friends.Where(x=>x.SocialNetworkName=="Facebook")) 
 }
 <div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

**FriendTeamModel:**

```
public class FriendTeamModel
{
    public long FriendTeam{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FriendModel> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

**FriendModel:**

```
public class FriendModel
{
    public string FriendID { get; set; }
    public string SocialNetworkName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public int FriendsCount { get; set; }      
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

***Error :***

> Models can only be used with expressions access field of homeownership, the index of one-dimensional array or custom indexer single parameter.

Thanks,

Comment: I would use a view model here with 1 IEnumerable<FriendModel> for twitter and one for facebook so that the splitting is done in the controller and not the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your view model to better suit your view

```
public class FriendTeamModel
{
    public long FriendTeam{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FriendModel> FacebookFriends { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FriendModel> TwitterFriends { get; set; }
}
```

And set those parameter values in controller, not in view. This way, in view, you will have

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{          
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)     
  <h3>Twitter</h3>
  <br />    
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TwitterFriends)                  

  <h3>Facebook</h3>
  <br />    
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaceookFriends) 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error basically means you can't do this :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friends.Where(x=>x.SocialNetworkName=="Twitter"))
```

Either loop through your `IEnumerable<FriendModel> Friends` if you want to display them all or use a filtering method that returns a single `FriendModel`, like :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friends.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.SocialNetworkName=="Twitter"))
```

Comment: exactly what is in  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friends.Where(x=>x.SocialNetworkName=="Twitter")) that are the problem. I did what you said, but same problem. Thanks

Comment: how to make the loop? when i use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friends) all appear

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add multiple items in one form. this article maybe help you:

- http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-dynamic-form/

> jQuery Dynamic Form is a plugin for jQuery. It gives the ability to
>   dynamically add fields based on HTML template. Update version 1.0 is
>   out and has been uploaded on Google Code. It includes two long awaited
>   features : nested fields duplication, and data injection. I’ll update
>   examples when I have time, however you already have a working example
>   package in the zip, go download it !
>   http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/downloads/list